# Вывод в консоли содержимое директории и поддиректорий и путь к поддиректориям и файлам

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 struct stat buf;
 int exists;
 DIR *d;
 struct dirent *de;

 d = opendir(".");
 if (d == NULL) {
 fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open \".\"\n");
 exit(1);
 }

 for (de = readdir(d); de != NULL; de = readdir(d)) {
   exists = stat(de->d_name, &buf);
 if (exists < 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s not found\n", de->d_name);
 } else {
  printf("%s %lld\n", de->d_name, buf.st_size);
 }
}
closedir(d);
return 0;
}
```

Всем доброго времени суток! У меня возникла проблема с выводом файлов и директорий в консоли Linux. То что я написал выводит содержимое корневой директории но у меня не получается вывести в консоли содержимое поддиректорий и путь к ним. За ранее простите за мой русский. Всем добра)))

Comment: См. функцию calc_size() [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425342).

Comment: [примеры кода рекурсивного обхода дерева директорий с помощью (среди прочего) nftw, readdir](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461144/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй это **man nftw**
Указываешь каталог, фукнцию которая будет вызываться при каждом найденном файле, глубину входа, и флаги. Вот пример.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
int found ( const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb,
            int typeflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf ) {

  // в sb храниться имя файла
  // в fpath храниться путь

} 

// а вызывается так.

nftw ( "/home/user/dir", found, 20, 0 );

// 20 - это глубина вхождения
```

Так понятно?

Comment: Да! Спасибо огромное!!!!